# How to check password length and chars

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a password field (char type).

How can i make sure it contains exectly 8 chars between a-z and 0-9 only?

What kind of check() should i use?

Ty!

Comment: That's a pretty terrible password constraint.

Comment: Why would you want to do that in SQL Server? This kind of validation should primarily be the concern of your UI and business logic layers.

Comment: I don't want to do that. But my lecturer asked me to do that. although it's a terrible password constraint :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure it's a great idea to do this but try something along the lines of this:

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(10) = '123a*dzx' 

SELECT 1 
WHERE  Len(@test) = 8 
       AND @test NOT IN (SELECT @test 
                         WHERE  @test LIKE '%[^a-z0-9]%')
```

You can try it out on <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/37219)</kbd>

Comment: The method seems fine although the `AND ...` part could be simplified [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/37225): `AND @test NOT LIKE '%[^a-z0-9]%'`.

Comment: Ty. I'm new in Sql.

Does it make sense like this:



    diver_password  char(8) not null check(Len(diver_password) = 8 
    AND diver_password NOT IN (SELECT diver_password 
    WHERE  @test LIKE '%[^a-z0-9]%'))

Comment: @AndriyM Or something like this: 
    diver_password  char(8) not null check(Len(diver_password) = 8 
       AND diver_password NOT IN ('%[^a-z0-9]%')),

Comment: @user3885474: No, I don't believe `NOT IN ('%[^a-z0-9]%')` would work actually. That would be same as `<> '%[^a-z0-9]%'`, which would be literal matching rather than pattern matching. You do need `NOT LIKE` there.

Comment: @AndriyM
so the correct syntax is:  

diver_password  char(8) not null check(Len(diver_password) = 8 
       AND diver_password not like('%[^a-z0-9]%'))